# How to calclutate different between two date in android

Tags: android, date

I have android application and I need to display the different between two date but I have a problem in this case

For example :
When tried to display the different between date 28/12/2016 and 01/01/2017

the result is 339 days , How I can solve this and when tried to display, I got a correct result. This is my code:

```
  public void Cal() {

    java.text.SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss");

    try {
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("2017/01/01"+ " " + "11:30:00");//end_date
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("2016/12/28"+ " " + "11:30:00");//start_date
        printDifference(date1, date2);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate) {

    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
    System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
    System.out.println("different : " + different);

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    System.out.printf(
            "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n",
            elapsedDays,
            elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you used when constructing your `SimpleDateFormat` has a problem. You used this:

```
yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss
```

But you should have used this:

```
yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss
```

From the documentation, lowercase `m` means minutes in an hour, which is appropriate for the timestamp portion of your format string, while uppercase `M` means months in the year.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaank youuu its workkkkkkking for me thank you very very very much